# Get-Package Returns More Than One Result, How to Loop Through and Remove All Results?

Tags: powershell

I'm currently running this script to remove ESET, however *sometimes* there are multiple results from $AppNames, which causes the script to error out.  I'd like to loop through each result, but I'm having trouble getting it to do so.

Here's my code:

```
# Uninstall apps
$AppNames = @("eset ")

$AppNames | ForEach-Object {
    $Package = (Get-Package -Name *$_*) | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogPath
    

    if ( $Package.ProviderName -eq "msi" ) {
        $Guid = $Package.FastPackageReference | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogPath -Append
        $Name = $Package.Name | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogPath -Append
        $Version = $Package.Version | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogPath -Append
        "Uninstalling $Name $Version" | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogPath -Append
        $Process = Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/x$Guid /quiet /norestart" -Wait -PassThru
        echo "Exit code: " | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogPath -Append
        $Process | Select ExitCode -ExpandProperty ExitCode | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogPath -Append
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

> Uninstalling ESET Remote Administrator Agent ESET Endpoint Antivirus 6.5.522.0 10.1.2050.0

So it's combining both results into a single string, and failing.

I'd like to not explicitly list out each ESET product, if possible. That works, but throws errors into the output and is less elegant.

Any ideas on how I can fix?

I tried adding additional ForEach-Object blocks in the uninstall loop, but I couldn't get it to properly select one of the results, uninstall, and move onto the next.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Package` returns all matching packages, so you'll have to loop through each entry.

Try this:

```
$AppNames | ForEach-Object {
    $Packages = (Get-Package -Name *$_*) | Tee-Object -FilePath $LogPath

    foreach ($Package in $Packages)
    {
        if ( $Package.ProviderName -eq "msi" ) {
            ..........
        }
    }
}
```